# Undefined reference to 'CRYPT_NUM_LOCK'

Tags: compiling, gcc, libraries

I am new to ubuntu and currently i am using 12.04 version of ubuntu. i am trying to compile a program using openssl libraries using gcc compiler. But it is giving errors: Undefined reference to 'Function name'. 
 I have installed openssl, libssl, libssh, libcrypto. All are updated and installed. I have placed my c file in home folder. But still its not working. [Output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur3PE.png)
please guide:

1. where should i place my code file to include all libraries.
2. How can i directly link these libraries to get included.

Thanks

Comment: Would be great if you show us your source code, but that is a typical linker error

Comment: i am trying to compile a openssl based dtls sample code downloaded from http://sctp.fh-muenster.de/dtls-samples.html

Comment: when i compiled it first, it was working and showing errors in code. then all of the sudden on 3rd / 4th compilation it started giving undefined reference error

Comment: after reading other forums about same error, i tried to compile it by:

 gcc dtls.c -o a  -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread 

program is compiled showing no errors but no output also. In actual some libraries are missing and code has mistakes. 

When i try to compile using: 

gcc dtls.c && ./a.out -lssl -pthread -lcrypto 

undefined reference error appear again...

Comment: You need to deference the compiling and the execution part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working here, with the options you provided in your last comment

`gcc dtls.c -o a -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread` and then execute it with `./a` or use it as one statement

`gcc dtls.c -o a -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread && ./a`

Comment: oh yes... and now i got what  && ./a means..  .. i was opening output file without linking libraries.. thanks a bundle... :)

Comment: You are welcome the `&&` means execute the following program if the further one exited with no error. Same as you would update your Ubuntu machine with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. It makes no sense to upgrade if the update exited with an error, so it will not be executed